# Finding the coefficient in the expansion of $\prod\limits_{m=1}^N \left(1-R^mA\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, products, pochhammer-symbol

I understand that $$\prod\limits_{m=1}^N \left(1-R^mA\right)$$ is a polynomial in $A$, and so can be written as $\sum\limits_{k=0}^N c_k A^k$ for some coefficients $c_k$.

I can't seem to figure out a closed form expression of $c_k$, any ideas?

Comment: See the [$q$-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol).

Comment: What do you actually need? A closed-form formula, just a formula or an algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the formula (4) on http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html what you want?

Comment: @Tiana The site has references for those symbols. You can have a check if you are not familiar with them.

Comment: would $c_k$ then be be $(-1)^k$ multiplied with everything else apart from $a^k$? thanks

Comment: @Tiana Sure, you got it.